# How to create a flat vortex force field?

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to make a sort of accretion disk around a black hole, except I can't figure out how to create a vortex that forms a flat ring shape rather than a tornado shape. I've tried scaling along the z axis, but if you scale it to 0, it just stops working altogether.

How do I flatten this vortex force field (for use with smoke effects) so that it will form a flat disk rather than a tornado shape?

[image]

I added a vortex force field. If I scale it to 0 along the z axis, the radial force it exerts on the particle system disappears. If I add a falloff to the force field, the radial force disappears also. This is my scene: imgur.com/GbIm3sE The dark gray circle in the center is the gravity lensing object, the sphere in the very center is the black hole object, and the spiraling lines mark where the vortex force field is. The rendered image is posted in an earlier comment of mine.I need particles to be sucked off of the star object on the right and spun around the black hole in a disk shape

Comment: [Something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIPQ6ANnr70)?

Comment: @sambler Yeah, except my emitter is taller than the vortex itself (a star) so when the smoke / particles fly off the star, they form a tall tube instead of a flat disk. I'm trying for something like this http://blogs.futura-sciences.com/e-luminet/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2015/02/cygx1-605x372.jpg

Comment: @hawkenfox If you scale to 0 along the z axis, the vortex no longer has an effect. When I set falloffs, the vortex no longer seems to have an effect either. If I scale the z force down without scaling it to 0, it still does the same thing. I'm trying to make an accretion disk (you can look it up if you don't know what that is because the appearance is important). It's not a prank, otherwise I wouldn't have done this work so far: http://imgur.com/dSitGLR

Comment: I added a vortex force field. If I scale it to 0 along the z axis, the radial force it exerts on the particle system disappears. If I add a falloff to the force field, the radial force disappears also. This is my scene: http://imgur.com/GbIm3sE The dark gray circle in the center is the gravity lensing object, the sphere in the very center is the black hole object, and the spiraling lines mark where the vortex force field is. The rendered image is posted in an earlier comment of mine.I need particles to be sucked off of the star object on the right and spun around the black hole in a disk shape

Comment: @Sanix25 you ought to add the last comment to your question above it's much clear ... while I try to work on it and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what is "emitter is taller than the vortex itself" but if you mean [forcing particles to move round while a star is quite big](http://imgur.com/eShmxTU) then you could setup force field faloff settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I hope this is what you are looking for?

[image]

[DOWNLOAD THE BLEND FILE HERE.](https://mega.nz/#!zEkmyK7D!_Vukb36DD2KPNrr8nmICUVnqumlFSXlvpBEihd3rFnE)

Comment: a link + image only answer won't be very useful if the link goes down. You should give a description of the technique used, maybe more UI screenshots.

Comment: @zeffii I would do that once the OP decides that it's the answer he wants. Basically I am still quite unsure if he is looking for this effect. Moreover Mega.co.nz never failed me :)